# Ajax Response from CakePHP Controller returning null

Tags: ajax, cakephp, controllers

I'm tryin to validate an input field with an ajax call to a cakephp controller
My Ajax is:

```
$("#UserAlphaCode").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '<?php echo $this->webroot ?>' + "/alpha_users/checkCode",
            data: ({code : $(this).val()}),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                alert (data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert("epic fail");
            }
        });
    });
```

My controller code

```
function checkCode() {
        Configure::write('debug', 0);
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $codePassed = $this->params['form']['code'];
        $isCodeValid = $this->find('count',array('conditions'=> array('AlphaUser.code' => $codePassed)));
        if ($isCodeValid == 0){
            $codeResponse = false;
        } else {
            $codeResponse = true;
        }
        echo json_encode ($codeResponse);   
    }
```

I'm pretty sure I'm using $this->params wrong here to access the data sent from the ajax request.  What should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

`$codePassed = $_POST['code']`

you might also try putting:

```
$this->log($codePassed,LOG_DEBUG);
```

somewhere in there and examine the output in `tmp/logs/debug.log`

Using firebug will help debug the transport.

Comment: After trying your suggestiong $codePassed = $_POST['code']
I am able to return that back to the alert(data)
I tested this by changing my controller output from
echo json_encode ($codeResponse);   
to
echo json_encode ($codePassed);

This worked.

But when I try to return

$isCodeValid I get a null response.

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with my $isCodeValid = $this->find('count',array('conditions'=> array('AlphaUser.code' => $codePassed)));

Comment: I checked the header content and I get nothing, but there is an error in the chrome debugger that says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'codeResponse' of null"

Comment: You're in the controller, right?
the line should read:  $isCodeValid = $this->AlphaUser->find(...

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why it would be returning null, but I normally use `$this->data` to fetch form data.

And did you try `debug($this->params)`? If you don't have a non-AJAX form to test the request from, use Firebug or Wireshark to see what is being return by the server for the `debug()` call—since it will break jQuery's AJAX handler by not being in JSON.